# How to show mobile no is already exits to particular row using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

i'm working on a add & remove row to add multiple user at a time with mobile no validation/available **(not in use)** . Its working fine. But when the mobile no is already in use for only row, Message is showing for the other rows.

Here my code html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.9.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/addmore.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dirPagination.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="nav-md" data-ng-cloak data-ng-app="AddMoreModule" data-ng-controller="AddMoreController">
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name="AddMoreForm" id="AddMoreForm" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-12 fade-in tada" style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="display table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="5%">Sr.No</th>
                                <th width="20%">Name</th>
                                <th width="20%">Mobile No</th>
                                <th width="25%"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="cap in data">
                                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="name">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="name" data-ng-model="cap.name"  placeholder="Name" required>                    
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Mobile No'" sortable="Mobile No">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobno" maxlength="10" data-ng-model="cap.mobno" data-ng-change="get_mobno(cap.mobno)" placeholder="Mobile No" required>
                                    <strong data-ng-show="mobnoerror" style="color:#FF0000;">{{MsgE}}</strong>                   
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" data-ng-click="addNewForm()" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Items" /> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="removeNewRow(cap.name,cap.mobno)" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-disabled="AddMoreForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="submitData()"/>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the angularJS Script

```
var AddMore = angular.module('AddMoreModule',['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ui.bootstrap'])
AddMore.controller('AddMoreController', function ($scope, $http)
{
/*Add & Remove row script starts here*/

    //to remove the row
    $scope.removeNewRow = function(name,mobno)
    {
        var index = -1;
        var comArr = eval( $scope.data);
        for(var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++)
        {
            if(comArr[i].name==name && comArr[i].mobno==mobno)
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(index===-1)
        {
        }
        $scope.data.splice(index,1);
    };

    //Dynamic row creation
    $scope.data = [{}];

    $scope.addNewForm = function()
    {
        $scope.data.push({});
    }
/*Add & Remove row script ends here*/


    $scope.get_mobno = function(mobno)
    {
        $http.post('get_mobno.php', { 'mobno':mobno } )
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
        {
            $scope.mobnoerror = false;
            if(data!="OK")
            {
                $scope.mobnoerror = true;
                $scope.MsgE = data;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.mobnoerror = false;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.submitData = function()
    {       
        var comArr = eval( $scope.data);        
        var name = new Array();
        var mobno = new Array();

        for( var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++ )
        {   
            name.push(comArr[i].name);
            mobno.push(comArr[i].mobno);
        }

        if($scope.AddMoreForm.$valid)
        {
            var answer = confirm("Do you want to Submit?")
            if (!answer)
            {

            }   
            else
            {                   
                //insert code come here
                alert("Data added successfully");
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("All fields are mandatory");
            $scope.AddMoreForm.submitted= true; 
        }
    }   
});
```

get_mobno.php shows Ok if Mobile No is available. **Now i'm little confused how to show message only particular row?**

Comment: $scope.MsgE = data; Here you may declare $scope.MsgE= new array() $scope.MsgE[index] = data. and loop it in frontend to show a message

Comment: How to do so? can you help me in detail